# Get date from week number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

If I have week 7 in 2017 what week date is the Monday in that week in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
=DATE(B9,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B9,1,1),3)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(B9,1,1),3)>3)+7*(A9-1)
```

is the least complicated formula I know which works for week numbers in Sweden (i.e. `Monday first day of week`, `ISO` rules for what is week `1`).

Comment: In the US, where the first day of the week is Sunday, the modified formula is: 
 
`=DATE(B9,1,1)+(A9-1)*7-(WEEKDAY(DATE(B9,1,1)))+2`

(As above, this assumes the year is in B9 and the week number in A9.)

Comment: What is supposed to be in B9 and A9 ?

Comment: B9 is year cell reference
A9 is week number cell reference

Answer (score 24):

### Short answer (A1==Week, B1==Year):

```
=DATE(B1;1;1)+((A1-1)*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1;1;1);3)
```

### Long answer:

```
DATE(<year>;1;1) // days since 1970 until the first day of the year
```

plus

```
((<week number>-1)*7) // how many days into the year is this week
```

minus

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(<year>;1;1);3) // how many extra days from previous year in first week
```

### PS:

This assumes Monday as the first day of week you have to change the arguments for [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) to change it to Sunday

Answer (score 8):

Because of this definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week) the 4th of January must be used instead the 1st. The 4th of January is the first day which is always in the week 1.

```
=DATE(B1;1;4)+((A1-1)*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1;1;4);3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ISO weeks, the accepted answer doesn't account for weeks overlapping on 2 technical years like **2020-w53**, which is from 28 Dec 2020 until 3 Jan 2021.

Therefore I'm using this formula instead:

```
=DATE(K2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(K2,1,1),2)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(K2,1,1),2)>3)+7*(L2-1) +1
```

Where **K** is the Year, and **L** is the Week number (split in 2 columns from yyyy-ww)

to have it in an arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(K2:K="",, DATE(K2:K,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(K2:K,1,1),2)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(K2:K,1,1),2)>3)+7*(L2:L-1) +1 ))
```

You can use `=ArrayFormula(if(E2:E="",,split(E2:E,"-")))` to split yyyy-ww in two columns.

NOTE: This formula would return the **Monday** (Which is the first day of the week in international standard, ISO)

Answer (score 0):

Worked this up for 2023. It will work through end of 2024 too .. that said the AND logic is flawed .. feel free to suggest something to make this better

```
=IFS(
AND(ISOWEEKNUM(A8)=52,YEAR(A8)<>YEAR(A7)),

DATE(YEAR(A8-1),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A8-1),1,1),3)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A8-1),1,1),3)>3)+7*(ISOWEEKNUM(A8)-1),

DATE(YEAR(A8),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A8),1,1),3)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A8),1,1),3)>3)+7*(ISOWEEKNUM(A8)-1)
)
```