# Get the last day of the week from a week number

Tags: google-sheets

I'm succesfully using the formula provided here in an answer here: [Get date from week number in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494217/get-date-from-week-number-in-google-sheets)

So, I have:

```
=DATE(2023,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,1),3)+7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,1),3)>3)+7*(C2-1)
```

Where C2 is a cell with the week number, and I'm getting the expected result 02/01/2023.

**What do I need to change to get the result of 08/01/2023? - the last date of the week?**

Thank you again for all of your help!

Part of my problem is probably that I can't work out what the bold parts refer to/mean/do:

=DATE(2023,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,1),3)**+7***(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,1),3)**>3)+7***(C2**-1**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a date that is `6` days later than the formula result, add `6` to that result, like this:

`=6 + date(2023, 1, 1) - weekday(date(2023, 1, 1), 3) + 7 * (weekday(date(2023, 1, 1), 3) > 3) + 7 * (C2 - 1)`

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Your formula looks unnecessarily complex. It is likely that there are much easier ways to get those dates, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
=LAMBDA(aix,MAX(FILTER(aix,WEEKNUM(aix,21)=C2)))(SEQUENCE(365,1,DATE(2023,1,1),1))
```

- 

[image]