Turn a list of dates into Fridays Only
Update:
Here is what I am trying to do. I have 3 columns of random dates; I'd like to combine these in one array and produce a column containing ONLY Friday dates (i.e., for weeks in which a date appears in original 3 columns. Weeks where there is no date should no appear in result column.)
Here is the sample sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_-ML2mCVAMPzfTX0z2BO70wMZemjkWk8uQ71o0OF5Q/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I hope this makes sense. Thank you all for your help.
I tried many online suggestions, but couldn't get it right

You could try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494217/get-date-from-week-number-in-google-sheets combined with the WEEKNUM function.

Displaying all Friday dates every week in a single column
The formula transforms all the given dates into Fridays on the corresponding week of the date. Afterwards, the unique function was used to remove duplicate dates.
You may try this:
=LET(a,TOCOL(C7:E27,1),SORT(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(a,1)+TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(6-TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKDAY(a)),1)),1)))))


TOCOL was used to combine the three columns into one while ignoring all of the empty cells (by setting the second parameter of TOCOL to 1).


WEEKDAY() was used to get the difference between the given date and the Friday of the corresponding week of the given date. The difference was then added to the given date so that it becomes a Friday.


UNIQUE and SORT were used to organize the dates.

Output:


If this resolves your issue, please click the accept button (check mark icon) on the left. This helps others in the community with similar questions, find solutions. If you don't see the accept button, feel free to let me know.

Yes, that worked. Thank you. Such relief. Cheers!

PSST! I can't find the Accept button you mentioned. Sorry!

@BadrVA It's the checkmark located on the left side of 0 in my answer. See this documentation for more information.

Kindly check this documentation.
